# Parse emoji to words nlp

Tags: python, nlp

My task is to parse emojis to words, so given a text `I was place at volleyball last year` I need to parse it to `I was 1st_place_medal at volleyball last year`.

```
{
 ........
 
 '': ':1st_place_medal:',
 '': ':2nd_place_medal:',
 '': ':3rd_place_medal:',
 '': ':AB_button_(blood_type):',
 '': ':ATM_sign:',
 '': ':A_button_(blood_type):',
 
 ........
}
```

Given the `UNICODE_EMO` dictionary above I tried running `convert_emojis`, but I ended up with `error: nothing to repeat at position 1`.

```
def convert_emojis(text):
    for emot in UNICODE_EMO:
        text = re.sub(u'('+emot+')', UNICODE_EMO[emot].replace(':', ''), text)
    return text
```

**NOTE: I m running my code on a jupyter notebook**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your dictionary keys is being interpreted as a regex repeater in `u'('+emot+')'`. As an example, if one of your keys is `'*'`, you would get `(*)`, which is an invalid repetition.

Try escaping the dictionary keys:

```py
u'('+re.escape(emot)+')'
```